# The type 'FileProvider' exists in both 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat And 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils in Visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

The type 'FileProvider' exists in both 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.I am Using Visual Studio 2022.Not Able To Understand Why This error showing .Please guide.

Target Framework android 12.0 using API 31

Comment: First, you can uninstall both packages in your project. Second, you can clean the obj and bin and rebuild them. Third, install the packages.

Comment: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat And Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat this two packages are not installed in my project .why showing error like that i dont understand

Comment: The FileProvider belongs to the Xamarin.Essentials, Please make sure you have the package.

Comment: Yes, Xamarin.Essentials already installed in my project.

Comment: Can you provide some code where the issue exists?

Comment: its solved by updating xamarin.Essential and xamarin.form Packages

Comment: Great! I made a summary for the question for other people to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

You can update the xamarin.Essential and xamarin.form Packages to solve the problem.